# Android + Robolectric: расположение классов с тестами

Tags: java, android

Верно ли расположены классы тестов, если они расположены так:
**/src/test/java**?

Answer (score 1):

Да.

/src/test - Unit тесты, который выполняются на машине
/src/androidTest - Intrumented тесты, которые выполняются на устройстве

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!